# Not able to delete Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I Create VM  using ARM Template but by adding links in osdisk and disk in vm Profile, may this is the main issue I thought.

Arm Template: Osdisk and disk code where I added vhd: URI:"https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-os.vhd"

```
"osDisk": {
            "osType": "Linux",
            "name": "prasadtest101",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-os.vhd"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "lun": 0,
              "name": "prasaddatadisk101",
              "createOption": "Empty",
              "vhd": {
                "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-data.vhd"
              },
```

The error showed in Azure portal while deleting Azure VM:

Failed to delete the virtual machine 'MyUbuntuVM'.

> Error: One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk
>   instance view for details.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What does the disk instance view say for the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, there is something confusing in the template you posted. When you use the `createOption` with the type `FromImage`, it means you will create a disk from the image you refer to. So the disk name in the template osDisk must be the same as the one in the storage container.

In your template, you should the name into the vhd name.

```
"osDisk": {
            "osType": "Linux",
            "name": "foobar-os",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-os.vhd"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "lun": 0,
              "name": "foobar-data",
              "createOption": "Empty",
              "vhd": {
                "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-data.vhd"
              },
```

This just an example for you to change. You can also change as you like. Or you can follow the whole steps from [Unmanaged Disks template formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-managed-disks-template-deployments#unmanaged-disks-template-formatting). And the example template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/93b5f72a9857ea9ea43e87d2373bf1b4f724c6aa/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json).

Comment: but now i am not able to delete that vm due to that "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-os.vhd" . i tried with portal and powershell but not able to delete that vm .

Comment: when i am clicking on that VM it show not found and in disk section show disks with failed status . I thought due to that failed disk VM is not going to deleted.

Comment: You can try to create a vhd file with the name of the disk that the vm reference in your storage. Then delete the vm.

Comment: i am also tried with resource.azure.com but not able to delete that vm

Comment: i tried with createing a vhd file with the name of the disk that the vm reference in my storage but not able to delete vm

Comment: I test as you, but I can delete the vm without error. So can you provide more infommation about the error?

Comment: what i understand is that  due to some issue with ARM template disk creation is corrupted and due to this corrupted disk i am not able to delete that VM

Comment: If there is no something important inside the vm, you can try to deallocate the vm and then delete the vm.

Comment: yes the problem is solved ...due to the vm is pinned in dashboard